# Como popular uma Grid com uma lista de usuários usando LiveBindings?

Tags: delphi

Como popular uma Grid com uma lista de usuários usando LiveBindings?

Tendo criado um tipo:

```object-pascal
TPessoa = class
private
  FId: integer;
  FNome: string;
  FDataNascimento: TDate;
public
  property Id: integer read FId write FId;
  property Nome: string read FNome write FNome;
  property DataNascimento: TDate read FDataNascimento write FDataNascimento;
end;
```

Adicionei alguns compoentes ao formulário:

> 1. TStringGrid
> 2. TDataGeneratorAdapter
> 3. TAdapterBindSource
> 4. TBindNavigator

[image: LiveBindings_form_and_components]

**`BindingList`** foi criado automáticamente.

Para alimentar o AdapterBindSource criei uma variável do tipo TObjectBindSourceAdapter em meu formulário:

```object-pascal
TMainForm = class(TForm)
  strgList: TStringGrid;
  DataGeneratorAdapter: TDataGeneratorAdapter;
  AdapterBindSource: TAdapterBindSource;
  bindNav: TBindNavigator;
  BindingsList: TBindingsList;
  LinkGridToDataSourceAdapterBindSource: TLinkGridToDataSource;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  procedure AdapterBindSourceCreateAdapter(Sender: TObject; 
    var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
private
  FPessoas: TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TPessoa>;
end;

...

procedure TMainForm.AdapterBindSourceCreateAdapter(Sender: TObject; 
  var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
begin
  ABindSourceAdapter := FPessoas;
end;
```

Minha dificuldade está em popular essa lista.
Para isso pensei:

```object-pascal
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  index: integer;
  pessoa: TPessoa;
begin
  FPessoas := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TPessoa>.Create(self);
  for index := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    FPessoas.Append;

    pessoa := TPessoa.Create;
    pessoa.Id := index;
    pessoa.Nome := 'Nome ' + index.ToString();
    pessoa.DataNascimento := StrToDate('01/01/2000') + index;

    FPessoas.SetDataObject(pessoa);
  end;
end;
```

Bom, isso não funciona!
**Como fazer?**
**Existe outras formas de fazer isso com LiveBindings?**

Delphi na versão XE7.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75037/como-fazer-livebindings-com-objetos-e-pegar-os-objetos-contidos

Answer (score 1):

Para popular o Grid com uma lista de objetos você deve usar TListBindSourceAdapter e não TObjectBindSourceAdapter.