# Como fazer livebindings com objetos e pegar os objetos contidos?

Tags: delphi, objetos, delphi-xe8

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum. Com o `Delphi XE8`, já fiz `livebindings` para ligar componentes de tela `TEdit` com objetos não visuais, porem não consigo ligar componentes de tela com objetos contidos em outros objetos:
Exemplo:

```
TEstado = class
  FUF: string;
end;

TCidade = class
  FNome: string;
  FEstado: TEstado;
end;
```

Neste caso consigo ligar o nome da cidade com algum componente da tela, mas não consigo pegar `cidade.estado.uf` para mostrar na tela.

Comment: Quando eu precisar editar essa lista? No caso eu tenho um botão que atualiza essa lista com outros valores, qual função eu chamo pra atualizar o componente visual? Pois se eu só atualizar a grid dessa forma ai não vai atualizar o componente visual pra mostrar os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Para disponibilizar a estrutura da sua classe para a LiveBinding utilize o componente "DataGeneratorAdapter". Crie as propriedades da sua classe nele, a partir daqui vc poderá ligar seus componentes visuais a esta estrutura.

Depois disso, utilize o componente "AdapterBindSource" para vincular a sua classe a essa estrutura criada no "DataGeneratorAdapter". Programe o evento "CreateAdapter" da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TForm1.AdapterBindSource2CreateAdapter(Sender: TObject;
  var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);

begin

     FLista := TObjectList<TPessoa>.Create;
     FLista.Add(TPessoa.Create('Filipe', 25, 'filipe@email.com'));
     FLista.Add(TPessoa.Create('Cíntia', 27, 'cintia@email.com'));
     FLista.Add(TPessoa.Create('Julio', 32, 'julio@email.com'));
     ABindSourceAdapter := TListBindSourceAdapter<TPessoa>.Create(Self,     FLista);

end;
```